# unable to install npm with node.js

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm trying to install node.js and npm. Although I was successfully able to install node.js version 16.13.0, I'm not able to use npm, despite selecting it as a package that must be installed along with node.js. After the installation, I ran `npm --version` but I got this error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'node-fetch-npm'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\myaccount\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v11.0.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-registry-fetch\node_modules\make-fetch-happen\index.js
- C:\Users\myaccount\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v11.0.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-registry-fetch\index.js
- C:\Users\myaccount\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v11.0.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\lib\remote.js
- C:\Users\myaccount\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v11.0.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\lib\git.js
- C:\Users\myaccount\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v11.0.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\lib\fetcher.js
- C:\Users\myaccount\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v11.0.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\lib\index.js
- C:\Users\myaccount\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v11.0.0\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\update-notifier.js
- C:\Users\myaccount\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v11.0.0\node_modules\npm\lib\cli.js
- C:\Users\myaccount\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v11.0.0\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\ap202\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v11.0.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-registry-fetch\node_modules\make-fetch-happen\index.js:6:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
Error: Cannot find module 'node-fetch-npm'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\myaccount\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v11.0.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-registry-fetch\node_modules\make-fetch-happen\index.js
- C:\Users\myaccount\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v11.0.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-registry-fetch\index.js
- C:\Users\myaccount\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v11.0.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\lib\remote.js
- C:\Users\myaccount\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v11.0.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\lib\git.js
- C:\Users\myaccount\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v11.0.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\lib\fetcher.js
- C:\Users\myaccount\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v11.0.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\lib\index.js
- C:\Users\myaccount\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v11.0.0\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\update-notifier.js
- C:\Users\myaccount\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v11.0.0\node_modules\npm\lib\cli.js
- C:\Users\myaccount\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v11.0.0\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\myaccount\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v11.0.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-registry-fetch\node_modules\make-fetch-happen\index.js:6:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
```

I have looked at multiple questions on StackOverflow and other online resources but nothing talks about the issue I'm facing.

Comment: is that file in your package.json or are you running `npm install node-fetch-npm`?

Answer (score 0):

Try installing a lower version of npm or reinstall.

https://github.com/coala/docker-coala-base/issues/182

Answer (score 0):

My problem is because there is a conflict with `npm` binary in my system while trying to run `vue create` project.

---

In my case, I have two `npm` binaries. One in `AppData\Roaming` and one in a custom path in `F:\Programs\nodejs\`. The latter binary produces the error., but not the AppData one.

My `node.exe` binary is living in the `F:\` drive.

Installing [`node-fetch-npm`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch-npm) (deprecated) and [`node-fetch`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch) via `npm i` installs the package in `AppData\Roaming`, but it suppose to be installed in the `F:\` drive.

So, I copied both package folders from `AppData\Roaming` into the `F:\` drive one.

Running `vue create` is now fixed.

Gracefully uninstalled the unused package in the AppData folder by `npm uninstall -g  node-fetch node-fetch-npm`.